# Simple code to open and set managing metadata in a pdf document using itextsharp

Tags: itext

I'm trying to do the following:

```
void changeTitle(string newfilename, string oldFilename, string title)
{    
 a) open a pdf file (newfilename)
 b) change the subject
 c) save the pdf file (oldFilename)
}
```

Can anyone help me with this simple code? I would prefer saveAs(Adobe 9), any itext.dll vesion you prefer. The original version is 1.4.

I've looked the http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/manipulating-existing-pdfs but couldn't find a solution

Comment: Define "change the subject." Are you talking about changing metadata? If so, which version of iText are you using? Also: which version of PDF do you expect. In PDF 2.0 (released a couple of weeks ago), the "info dictionary" has been deprecated in favor of XMP. Does your PDF have XMP? All in all, your question isn't accurate enough. Please improve your question.

Comment: Is this better?

Comment: I assume that ddl is DLL. You want a C# solution?

Comment: Yes, C# solution

Comment: I don't have much time to answer now, but in Java it is done like this: [old iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/question/how-add-delete-retrieve-information-pdf-using-custom-property) / [new iText](http://developers.itextpdf.com/content/best-itext-questions-stackoverview/general-questions-about-itext/itext7-how-add-delete-retrieve-information-pdf-using-custom-property). It is fairly easy to convert this code to C# code. Of course: if your PDF contains XMP metadata, you need some extra code. Does your PDF contain XMP metadata?